# Bespoke form as widget in Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I'm new to Orchard and MVC, but I'd like to create a form on the front-end that saves the input to an external database. If the user's submitted form data is valid, it will be saved to an external database and then a confirmation view will need to be displayed in place of the form. I need this to use AJAX but I'm not sure how to go about doing it in Orchard.

It's important that the form is displayed as a widget so that I can easily place it on various pages in my site. Any ideas on how this can be done using AJAX including model validation?

I've tried creating widget content part and rendering the view using the driver display method. In the view I have a form that submits the view model to my own controller, but I'm not sure how to send back the validation errors and confirmation view one the data has been saved.

Comment: Not sure how orchard works but most validations such as lengths, required field and type checking can be performed by decorating your model properties with attributes such as, [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]. If you have logic that falls outside of the standard and you need to use business logic to validate then you should add the error to the model state using ModelState.AddModelError("","Invalid something"). I did not add this as an answer because this works best when using -->@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account")) or AjaxBeginForm. I am not sure how your controller is being called.

Comment: If you are rendering the markup via a json result from an ajax call then you will have to send special errors back in the Ajax success function.

Comment: Hi @Irb, I've given my view model all of the attributes, but my form is inside the view of a widget view inside my custom module. It looks like the built in Model validation isn't available in Orchard's front-end so I can just use Ajax.BeginForm and I'd prefer not to do it using Json so that I don't have to worry about the validation.